# Return only unrepeated first word of companyname

Tags: sql, sql-server

**This is my table**

```
EmpID      EmpName          CompanyName                            CompanyID
123         Josep       Kramer Levin Naftalis & Frankel LLP            468
123         Josep       Thompson Hine LLP                              567
801         Simon       Ogletree Deakins International LLP             222
801         Simon       Ogletree, Deakins, Nash PC                     916
602         alen        Baker Co Ltd                                   732
602         alen        Baker Mcken  Ltd                               242
```

Condition is Result will return, if the first word of the company name is not same, Ex:**Baker** and **Ogletree** these words are  more then once so it is not include as result

**My Output like this**

```
EmpID   EmpName           Company Name                            CompanyID
123       Josep       Kramer Levin Naftalis & Frankel LLP            468
123        Josep      Thompson Hine LLP                              567
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: Ms Sql Server Database

Answer (score 0):

This one is written for Oracle:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT table.*, 
               LEAD(company, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY companyid) AS next_company 
          FROM table)
 WHERE SUBSTR(company, 0, INSTR(company, ' ') - 1) != SUBSTR(next_company, 0, INSTR(next_company, ' ') - 1) AND next_company IS NOT NULL;
```

Edit: I see now you comment, that you're using SQL Server. It's probably not very different but I don't have the skills to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting this to mean that you want all employees that have different first words for the company name, where the first word is separated by a space.

You can use window functions in combination with string functions to get this information:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(left(company, charindex(' ', company + ' '))) over (partition by empid) as minfirstword,
             max(left(company, charindex(' ', company + ' '))) over (partition by empid) as maxfirstword
      from t
     ) t
where minfirstword <> maxfirstword;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7d/2415) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Ya Exactly what you told was correct .i need all employees where the first word of the company is not same name the word is separated by a space       But your query shows some error

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like this

```
create table #EmployeeTemp (EmpID int, Name nvarchar(100), Company nvarchar(100), CompanyID int)

insert into #EmployeeTemp (EmpID, Name, Company, CompanyID)
values
(11,    'Alberto',  'Baker  Mec Ltd',   25),
(11,    'Alberto',  'Baker  rel LLP',   26),
(12,    'Ameez',    'Baker  Mec Ltd',   25),
(12,    'Ameez',    'Wrong  Part LLP',  27)

Select EmpID, FirstWord, Count(FirstWord) as 'Counted', Count(FirstWord) over (partition by EmpID,FirstWord) 'CountByWord'
into #EmployeeFinal
from (
SELECT EmpID, CASE CHARINDEX(' ', Company, 1)
                         WHEN 0 THEN Company
                         ELSE SUBSTRING(Company, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Company, 1) - 1)
                         END as 'FirstWord'
from #EmployeeTemp) src
group by EmpID, FirstWord

Select * from #EmployeeFinal where Counted = 1 and CountByWord = 1
```

So, you will select only first word of company, count how many times that word repeats by employee and then select only those that you want

This is the result:

```
EmpID   FirstWord   Counted CountByWord
 12       Baker        1        1
 12       Wrong        1        1
```